# How to get children of parent element (only first match [0])

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
<ul class="resource">
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="resource">
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="resource">
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get how many locations are in the resources (it's always the same number of locations for each resource). So in this example the answer is 3.

I tried it doing the following:

```
$(".resource > .location").length // Returns 9 (obvious)
$(".resource")[0].children(".location") // Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).children is not a function
```

The only that works are:

```
$(".location").length / $(".resource").length // I won't use this one
$($(".resource")[0]).children(".location") // I'm using this one at this moment
```

It looks dirty. If I'm not wrong, this is doing: "get all the resources from the DOM, give me only the first one, get the first resource from the DOM".
The page has thousands of resources so I'm trying to optimize the code as maximum as possible.

Can I do it in one "DOM's call"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$(".resource")[0].querySelectorAll(".location").length`

Comment: And why not counting it server side, before rendering it? BTW, why do you need to count them?

Comment: @A.Wolff because I need to show them in a proportional width. If there are 4, I need each location with a 25% width. I said that always have the same locations but is not completely true. The problem is that there are different reports (one report = one page), and one can have 4 locations, other 5, other 3... So the number of locations in one report is always the same, but not all the reports have the same number of locations.

Comment: @Kamae I'm not a CSS guru but that would be for sure the purpose of CSS [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). So depending which browsers you need to support, i guess it could be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should re-ask a new question regarding your expected behaviour.

Comment: @A.Wolff well, I don't think it's a XY problem, because things are more complex than I can ask here so I can't explain how it works the whole website only to know one functionality in specific language, because even if I'm applying it bad, I could use that knowledge to do other things. Anyway, I really appreciate your suggestion, many thanks. I've checked flexbox but I don't know which browser will be used for the users so I don't want to worry about that. In addition I need 2 static fields at the beginning and 1 static at last, and I didn't find how to do that (only first and last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo selector like following.

```
$('resource:eq(0) .location').length;
```

Or [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) like following.

```
$('resource:first .location').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:first-child` selector

```
$('.resource:first-child .location');
```

Comment: Beat me to it so I'll just comment on yours, you can also use .first() like so $('.resource').first().find('.location').length

Comment: @CalebO'Leary yes, you can do that, but then you are funning 3x the amount of jquery functions instead of just one.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work for me because my code is more complex than the example and it's still getting all the locations, but it's working well in the reduced example so it's my fault.
It works fine with :first

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vanilla JS`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.resource:first-child .location').length;
```

Comment: Yea. He could. But then he doesnt get all of the jQuery _magic_ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This too should work fine:

```
 $('.resource:first > .location').length;
```

Or:

```
$('.resource').first().children('.location').length;
```

```js
alert( $('.resource:first > .location').length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="resource">
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="resource">
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="resource">
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
    <li class="location"></li>
</ul>
```